# git reset preserving several files

Tags: git

I have a bunch of files in a directory, and will version several files among all.

My git history will then look like the following:

```
commit0: Initial empty commit
commit1: start versioning file a.txt
commit2: edit a.txt
commit3: start versioning file b.txt
commit4: edit b.txt
...
```

After a while, I want to rollback all my changes, and come back to the state of commit0.
However, doing `git reset --hard commit0` will delete a.txt and b.txt

Is there a way to rollback all the changes but not delete the files that were added ?

Thanks,

Comment: The addition of the files _are_ part of the changes.  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: imagine a folder with a thousand files, named 0001.txt to 1000.txt.
I want to start tracking 0500.txt, then add a line to it and commit my changes.
Then start tracking 0501.txt and add a line to it.
In some cases, I want to revert those changes. So basicly retrieve the state of my repo before I started to track those files.
But I don't want the rollback to delete neither 0500.txt nor 0501.txt

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `--hard`.

from commit 4:

```
git reset commit0
git checkout commit1 -- a.txt
git checkout commit3 -- b.txt
```

Comment: The soft reset doesn't rollback the changes. It just removes them from the index.
I need the files to retrieve the state they had before starting to track them